# api-platform swagger issue

Tags: symfony, swagger-ui, symfony4, api-platform.com

I am trying to develop an API using api-platform and got issues with swagger documentation.

To illustrate my issue, i have created a new project with 2 basic entities provided in official documentation :
https://api-platform.com/docs/distribution.

I want a full nested object book when calling GET resource for reviews and use a IRI when calling POST, so i use serialization groups as explained here :

https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization

Api seems working as expected when i try a POST :

```
{
    "book": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "rating": 5,
    "body": "Interesting book!",
    "author": "Kévin",
    "publicationDate": "September 21, 2016"
}
```

Got this error : Nested documents for attribute \"book\" are not allowed. Use IRIs instead
With iri such as /api/books/1 review is created.

But swagger doc made me crazy :

For GET /api/reviews it's ok with a full book object :

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "rating": 0,
    "body": "string",
    "author": "string",
    "publicationDate": "2018-09-22T12:51:42.454Z",
    "book": {
      "id": 0,
      "isbn": "string",
      "title": "string",
      "description": "string",
      "author": "string",
      "publicationDate": "2018-09-22T12:51:42.454Z",
      "reviews": [
        null
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

But for POST got an empty object and i was expecting an IRI :

```
{
  "rating": 0,
  "body": "string",
  "author": "string",
  "publicationDate": "2018-09-22T12:51:42.483Z",
  "book": {}
}
```

I have tried ApiProperty() annotation too to force documentation without success ..

If i remove my normalization and denormalization group, documentation is correct, am i missing something or doing something wrong with my groups ?

Here is full code :

https://github.com/lwillems/api-platform-test

Thanks for help

Regards

Comment: Maybe POST with "book" : bookId ? Just a quick guess.

Comment: adding bookid in review only add the possibility to pass a book object with id instead of iri, but no effect on swagger doc ...

Comment: I didn't suggest to change anything in the backend code. Just not nest the id in the request JSON. What does that do?

Comment: My issue is related to generated swagger doc not request